# How can I access search button of AppBarTextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I couldn't access search button of AppBarTextField widget; I gave widget below;

```
AppBarTextField(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.back();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          searchButtonIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          centerTitle: true,
          defaultHintText: "Ara",
          searchContainerColor: Colors.white,
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          autofocus: false,
          controller: searchController,
          title: Text(
            "Müşteri Listesi",
            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          onBackPressed: _onRestoreAllData,
          onChanged: _onSearchChanged,
        );
```

This is what I mean;

[image]

What I did;

```
searchButtonIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("my value");
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
```

I did like above, it works. when I press search button it print my value but it doesn't do its main feature e.g it doesn't open text field to type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom search delegate for your search. the example below show help you

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.length < 3) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Search term must be longer than two letters.",
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    }
    
return ListView(
children:[
// SEARCH RESULTS HERE
]);
    
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is called everytime the search term changes. 
    // If you want to add search suggestions as the user enters their search term, this is the place to do that.
    return Column();
  }
}
```

Then call this customSearchDelegate in your IconButton

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
  onPressed: () {
    showSearch(
      context: context,
      delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: thanks you for your response, I got you. your answer is true but it takes too much time for me because as I can see, I need to return my body values into CustomSearchDelegate. Actually, what I want is that I want to open keyboard when I press that search button.

Comment: take a look at this https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did what I want;

```
AppBar(
      leading: isTyping
          ? IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                isTyping = false;
                setState(() {});
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back))
          : IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.back();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: [
        isTyping
            ? IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  /* isTyping = true; */
                  _onRestoreAllData();
                  setState(() {});
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.close))
            : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  isTyping = true;
                  focusNode.requestFocus();
                  setState(() {});
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
      ],
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: isTyping
          ? TextField(
              onChanged: _onSearchChanged,
              controller: searchController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Ara",
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  )))
          : Text(
              "Müşteri Listesi",
              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.black),
            ),
      elevation: 0,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isSearch = false;
```

First assign a variable

- then do the if check for  Appbar

```
     AppBar(
            actions: [
                          isSearch == true
                              ? SizedBox(
                                  width: 350,
                                  height: 70,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              isSearch = false;
                                              setState(() {});
                                            },
                                            icon: const Icon(Icons.close)),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                                    controller: searchController,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                 
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fastfood_rounded))
                        ],
                        title: isSearch == false
                            ? const Text("viewPage")
                            : const SizedBox.shrink(),
```

if isSearch == true ? show  textfield  else show the current widget.

*Manage the entire screen with a simple variable.*